# ini_set for connected php files advices

Tags: php, ini-set

In a content management system, a page load usually involves many php files. I'd like to ask to increase the `memory_limit` or `max_execution_time`, should i put ini_set on the top of every involving php files, or the first loaded php file is enough?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you only need to specify this in the first file loaded, which is usually your front controller.